# Saving comments in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem storing multiple comments by multiple users, like in Facebook (where many users comment on a single status update or photograph, etc).

Comment: What kind of problems do you have? Where is your broken code?

Comment: You need to understand database design, many to many relations, look here http://en.tekstenuitleg.net/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html

Comment: i wouldn't downvote. takes a while to learn if u start from scratch

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee: Downvotes are intended to indicate that "*this question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".

Comment: "I am having problems while walking", it's not even about the research effort, it's about how to describe the problem. In this case we don't know what problems do you really have while walking, does your feet hurt, or you are losing balance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To accomplish something like facebook comments you would need multiple tables.
A simplified version would have a schema of the following type:

```
+-------------+ 
| User        |
+-------------+
| user_id     |
| name        |
| email       |
+-------------+

+-------------+ 
| Activities  |
+-------------+
| activity_id |
| type        |
| content     |
| user_id     |
| date        |
+-------------+

+-------------+ 
| Comments    |
+-------------+
| comment_id  |
| activity_id |
| user_id     |
| comment     |
| likes       |
| date        |
+-------------+
```

Then to retrieve the comments of an activity, your query would look like

```
SELECT * FROM Activity
NATURAL JOIN Comments
NATURAL JOIN Users
WHERE activity_id = ?
ORDER BY Comments.date
```

- Relfor

Answer (score 0):

Each comment has its own ID. This should be an auto_increment field in the MySQL database. So the "comment" table in the database should have fields something like comment id, user id, object id (photo, status, etc), timestamp.

Then you're also going to have separate tables for users and objects, which will have their own id fields. That way you can match up a comment to a user, by the comment's user_id matching the users's id.